# Is it possible to return the combined result from both the threads using below implementation?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to return the combined result from both the threads using 
 below implementation? It can be done via Future Task, but is it possible to
 do in the below implementation.
 Can I access one thread's data in another thread and sum it to return the correct result??

```
 package concurrent.programming.multithreading;

 import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
 import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
 import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
 import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
 import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

 public class CopyOfAverageImplementation {


 public static double getAvg(int start,int end, int elements){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i= start;i<=end;i++){
        sum+=i;
     }
    return sum/elements;
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int list[] = new int[1000000];
    CountDownLatch latch =new CountDownLatch(100000);
    System.out.println("Adding elements to the list");
    for(int i=0 ;i<100000;i++){
        list[i]=i;
        System.out.print(" " + list[i]);
        latch.countDown();
    }
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Done Adding elements to the list");

    final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    pool.execute(new Runnable() {
        double a;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            a= getAvg(0, 49999,100000);
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    });
    pool.execute(new Runnable() {
        double b;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            b= getAvg(50000, 100000,100000);
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(b);;

        }
    });
    System.out.println("Done");
    pool.shutdown();


}
```

}

Comment: You run the code and tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the sum as a member of the object and have both the threads access and update it as shared value. In order to make sure the update is correct the method that updates the sum needs to be synchronized.